# Are Experimental Functions like DatabaseReference not available on Mathematica for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sql, databases, raspberry-pi

I tried calling DatabaseReference and RelationalDatabase on version 12.3.1.0 for the Raspberry Pi, and found that the functions were not defined.  I see in the documentation that they are Experimental functions. (They are available on my Mac's Version 12.3.1.0.)

Are all of the experimental functions missing from the Raspberry Pi program? Is there any chance that Version 13 will soon be available on Raspberry Pi with these functions supported?

Thanks to all at Wolfram Research for all that Mathematica does and hopefully will soon do on the Raspberry pi as well.
Steve

Comment: It may be that those functions require underlying code or libraries that do not work on the ARM build of Mathematica, but that's just a guess. I note that those functions also aren't available on the cloud version of Mathematica.

Comment: Yes, that might be. The fact that the functions are not in the cloud version of Mathematica is suggestive as well.  Thank you.